# Como executar um <p:confirm> através do Bean?

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Minha dúvida é: Como posso executar um `<p:confirm>` através do Bean?

Vou explicar melhor o problema. Durante a inserção de um registro eu preciso verificar se o mesmo já existe na lista no qual estou inserindo o CPF . Até aqui tudo bem. Eu dou uma mensagem com `FacesMessages SEVERITY_ERROR` e pronto!

Mas existe uma regra de negócio que deve verificar se nos últimos 6 meses o registro, no caso CPF, já participou de outra ficha. Neste caso a regra diz que deve-se fazer uma pergunta ao usuário se ele confirma a nova inserção.

Bem, quando faço a verificação no Bean, eu não sei como renderizar um componente na tela para que o usuário confirme e continue o processamento, ou seja, a inserção do registro nesta nova ficha!

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, segue o código:

```
public void abrirConfirm() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('WidgetVarDoDialog').show();");
}
```

esse código serve para abrir um `<p:dialog>` também.

Comment: Rafael, eu consigo capturar no Bean qual botão foi pressionado, por exemplo se foi pressionado o botão1 ou botão2?

Comment: Bem dentro do `confirm` você pode colocar dois botões e definir um `actionListener` para cada.

Comment: Eu fiz e deu certo em partes. Ocorre que mesmo fazendo isso eu não estou conseguindo desviar o fluxo dentro do bean e quando pressionado não, eu preciso encerrar a continuação do Bean. para que a inserção dos dados não ocorra. Quando pressionado sim, devo permitir.